# How can I render ANSI code blocks such command output using mkdocs?

Tags: mkdocs

One common use-case while writing documentation is to have examples of command output. Some tools also product ANSI (colored) output, so there is a real need to show output using their original colors.

Still I was not able to get command output into code blocks in mkdocs, something that worked quite fine with Sphinx via command-output extension.

Any idea on how this can be achieved? I really want to avoid the screenshot route.

Comment: Maybe [code execution](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/wiki/MkDocs-Plugins#code-execution-variables--templating) plugin like Jupyter, which supports calling shell command as format `!ping example.com` will help. I'm not familiar with Sphinx, but is `.. command-output::` [about it](https://sphinxcontrib-programoutput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#directive-command-output)? I think it's better to put a link to this in your question, to clarify. Did I understand correctly that your question about REPL of shell commands but in mkdocs?